# SSRS 2005 - Customize Parameter Handling

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a report using SSRS 2005. Report has 5 parameters. 4 of them will be displayed and will be selected by user and 1 (let's say ID) needs to be hidden.

I want to pass value of ID parameter from my ASP.NET application which will be name of logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
var report = new LocalReport();
report .ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Path/To/Report.rdlc");
ReportParameter param= new ReportParameter("Name", "Value");
report .SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { param});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my report is server report.

Comment: Faisal i'am happy to help you